# fgets() превышение длины массива Си

Tags: linux, c

Например, у меня есть массив

```
char message[10];
```

и в него я считываю с клавиатуры строку

```
fgets(message, 10, stdin);
```

Может случиться ситуация, когда длина строки, введенная с клавиатуры, будет превышать размер массива `message`. Как отследить это превышение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
char message[10];
fgets(message, 10, stdin);
unsigned len = strlen(message);
if (message[len-1] != '\n' && !feof(stdin)) puts("Not fit...");
```

Comment: `feof()`-у тут не откуда появится. Это состояние определяется при чтении и в таком случае `fgets()` вернет 0. Остается просто `if (len == 9 && message[9] != '\n') puts(...)`. Если дело серьезное, то в этот момент и надо пытаться читать (например, fgetc() с анализом на EOF) и если EOF нет, то в самом деле строку урезали и надо делать `ungetc()`

Comment: По идее, чтобы проверить, что строка состоит из девяти символов, последний из которых не NL, длину-то ее считать не надо.

Comment: @avp, разве в случае, когда последняя строка файла не заканчивается переводом строки, `gets` её не прочитает?

Comment: @avp, https://ideone.com/jzmjjy - действительно, нолик - а что же тогда делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, если последняя строка без `\n`, то тоже прочтет. Следующее чтение даст EOF. Именно это и надо отслеживать, чтобы надежно определить урезание строки. Впрочем, проще всего использовать не `fgets`, а [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: @bipll, а что будет если строка короче? Правильно, в 9-м символе будет что угодно, кроме относящегося к делу.

Comment: Зачем же что угодно. Пусть там будет то, что мы положили. Нужно написать `message[9] = 42;`, а потом спрятаться и посмотреть, что будет дальше. Если после fgets `message[9]` стал нулем, значит строка длинная. Если при этом `message[8]` не NL, значит она очень длинная.

Comment: @bipll, но есть вариант без `\n`, когда прочитана вся строка - конец файла.

Comment: Да, и что? Чему в данный момент это противоречит? Как из этого следует необходимость вызывать `strlen` на пустом месте?

Comment: @bipll, я не про `strlen` - его действительно можно не вызывать.

Comment: А я как раз про  strlen. :-\

Answer (score 1):

Дабы лишний раз не считать длину строки (если оно не требуется) лучше установить предпоследний байт буфера в ноль до чтения и проверять его. Также в коде приведён пример обработки всевозможных исключительных ситуаций.

```
#define BUF_SZ 10

// ...

char message[BUF_SZ];
char *rv;
message[BUF_SZ-2] = 0;
rv = fgets (message, BUF_SZ, stdin);

if (!rv) {
  fprintf (stderr, "fgets() failed.\n");
} else if (message[BUF_SZ-2] && message[BUF_SZ-2] != '\n') {
  fprintf (stderr, "fgets() have't read full string.\n");
} else if (feof (stdin)) {
  fprintf (stderr, "fgets() encountered an unterminated string before eof.\n");
} else {
  printf ("Successfully recieved a string: %s", message);
}
```

Comment: 1. В этом коде feof никогда не вернёт true. 2. https://ideone.com/jzmjjy - та же проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вернёт если строка короче 10 символов и отсутствует перевод строки...

Comment: https://ideone.com/9Sueen - да, точно :) Но ведь в таком случае прочитано как раз всё, поему у тебя выводится про _"incomplete string"?_

Comment: @Qwertiy да, немного двусмысленно получилось... я исходил из POSIX'овскими определениями строки (line): «последовательность нуля или более не-<newline> символов, завершаемых <newline>-символом». «Incomplete string» — первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: К сожалению, в общем случае все равно не будет работать (поскольку 0-ли тоже могут быть прочитаны fgets (как работать с такими данными дальше это уже другой вопрос)). А вот `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)` позволит сделать что-то осмысленное...

Comment: пока в Си не примут — не торт... а в Си не примут — не любят там буферы с malloc'ом выделяемые на стороне функции...

Comment: Да ее написать и отладить часа за глаза хватит. Будете свою всюду где GNU нет таскать (если есть охота к переносу во что ни попадя)